# SpeechSynthesizer doesn't give the natural pause for full-stop in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, text-to-speech, avspeechsynthesizer, avspeechutterance

I am working on a text to speak task. In which I am facing problem that if I got the text for example: `Hello everyone. 2 minutes to go.` Then using code below for speech synthesizer, It considers whole text as one sentence and doesn't give a natural pause after `Hello everyone.`. It speaks whole text as one sentence just like there is no `. (full stop)` after `Hello everyone`. **This happens only if there is a number after punctuation mark** `. (full stop)`

```
let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "Hello everyone. 2 minutes to go.")
utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")
utterance.rate = AVSpeechUtteranceDefaultSpeechRate
synthesizer.speak(utterance)
```

If you are concerned how I'm initializing session and synthesizer then here is the code below:

```
let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
do {
    try session.setCategory(.playback, options: .duckOthers)
    try session.setActive(true)
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@Umair This not just happens when you write something that starts with a numeric value but it also happens when your next sentence is not started with a capital letter e.g.`Hello everyone. two minutes to go.`In fact these are the mistakes in your text writing and not any problem with `AVSpeechSynthesizer`. Grammatically if you want to write this text then it should be in one of the following ways.

> Hello everyone. Two minutes to go.

or

> Hello everyone, 2 minutes to go.

both of the above statements will give the exact answer for your question. another line can work for you but that is not an appropriate sentence. `Hello everyone,. 2 minutes to go.`

Hope this can help